# Tool or T-SQL method to generate/insert code comment sections

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I am looking for a way to insert code comment blocks semi-automatically in all the views, stored procedures, and UDFs in a database (basically every code-based module).  I'm fine with generating the ALTER statements and reviewing them myself before running the scripts, I was just looking for a reliable way to generate them.  I am not looking for a method to alter the SSMS template, which will not help me alter the existing SQL modules

Obviously SPs contain `AS` or `AS BEGIN`, but views only contain `AS` and I need to ensure that it takes account of varying whitespace.

Comment: Actually SPs do not need a Begin immediately after the As statement, (i.e., the entire body of the SP does not need to be in a Begion End Block...

Comment: @Charles, yes, of course - I guess that's another possible parsing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to handle this manually - I code-generated the comments and pasted them into each SP, VIEW, TRIGGER and FUNCTION...

Answer (score 1):

[SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features) (free) has "SQL Snippets" which might be useful, but to add things retrospectively and automatically could be a pain.

BTW, [stored procs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) do not have to have to BEGIN/END

From this BOL link, it shows they are optional (edit: as Charles mentioned I see now)

```
...
<sql_statement> ::= 
{ [ BEGIN ] statements [ END ] }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use SQL Compare (from Red Gate) to dump the whole schema to a series of .SQL files.  You can then easily add some text to the head of the files before re-running SQL Compare to commit them to the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Visual Studio Team System Database Edition, you should be able to work through the process described by Joel (import the schema from your database into a SQL Server 2XXX project), then tailor the Code templates provided by Visual Studio.  Visual Studio help contains information on customizing these templates.  See the topic: "How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates" for more information.

HTH

--
Ozziemedes

Comment: Unfortunately this gig is one of those things where SQL Server was the plan, and now it's not, so they aren't investing in any SQL Server tools.  I ended up writing something in our general health check procedures which generates the code blocks specific to each module which doesn't have one and then pasting them from the regular system health check results as they are updated with changes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this tool will be helpful
http://www.softtreetech.com/isql.htm